# Learning Binary Search in python 3.7

Tags: runtime-error, binary-search, python-3.7

I found this code on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

```
# Python Program for recursive binary search.

# Returns index of x in arr if present, else -1
def binarySearch (arr, l, r, x):

    # Check base case
    if r >= l:

        mid = l + (r - l)/2;

    # If element is present at the middle itself
    if arr[mid] == x:
        return mid

    # If element is smaller than mid, then it 
    # can only be present in left subarray
    elif arr[mid] > x:
        return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x)

    # Else the element can only be present 
    # in right subarray
    else:
        return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x)

    else:
        # Element is not present in the array
        return -1

# Test array
arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 10, 40, 50, 80, 140, 200, 2000, 100]
x = 50

# Function call
result = binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr)-1, int)

if result != -1:
    print ("Element is present at index %d" % result)
else:
    print ("Element is not present in array")
```

However, when I run it I get this problem: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float 
I'm not sure how to convert do that. I attempted to set the entire array as an int but that didn't work or replace x with int and that didn't work either.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `l + (r - l)/2` is float. Try rounding it.

Comment: Ok let me try that. Thanks
Just tried it now I'm getting is error:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'type'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on this line:

```
mid = l + (r - l)/2;
```

In Python 3 **/** does floating point division and as **mid** is used as an array index it needs to be an int. To do integer division use **//**

```
mid = l + (r - l) // 2;
```

There is also another issue with the call to the function:

```
result = binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, int)
```

The last parameter should not be **int** but **x** (the variable you are searching for):

```
result = binarySearch(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, x)
```

when you pass in **int** as the last parameter you'll get an error **TypeError: unorderable types: int() > type()**

Comment: Ok, just I made those changes and it works now. Thank you so much.